# TestNG annotation inheritance

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, testng

I have a base class, an intermediate class, and a test class with annotations in each of the classes and the classes inhere. Basically test inheres intermediate and intermediate inheres base. In theory it should execute the annotations in base first then the annotations in intermediate and finally test.

According to TestNG documentation at https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations it should work.
"Behaviour of annotations in superclass of a TestNG class

The annotations above will also be honored (inherited) when placed on a superclass of a TestNG class. This is useful for example to centralize test setup for multiple test classes in a common superclass.

In that case, TestNG guarantees that the "@Before" methods are executed in inheritance order (highest superclass first, then going down the inheritance chain), and the "@After" methods in reverse order (going up the inheritance chain)"

```
public void base(){
@BeforeTest
public void setup(){
    //initialize webdirver & stuff
    }
@AfteTest
public void tearDown(){
    //quit driver
   }
}   


public void logIn extends base() {
@BeforeClass
public void login(){
    //do stuff
    }
@AfterClass
public void logout(){
    //do stuff
    }  
}


public void test1 extends login() {
@test
public void test(){
    //do stuff
    }
}
```

My idea with this was to initialize the webdriver, then login, then execute the test, after that logout and finally quit the driver, but it is not working. When executing the test, it shows an error in the login class because the driver is null. It turns out that TestNG is not considering the annotations in the base class.

I got rid of the login class and it does the driver initialization. I also tried with different annotations with the three class idea I had, but nothing works.

```
public void base(){
    @BeforeTest
    public void setup(){
        //initialize webdirver & stuff
       }
    @AfteTest
    public void tearDown(){
       //quit driver
       }
}       


public void test1 extends base() {
@test
public void test(){
    //do stuff
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make this work or a better solution?

Comment: Can you run in debug mode with debug point in base and intermediate class. TestNG executes it correctly but are you ensuring that the base class driver is inherited into intermediate and test class without any access specifier restrictions

Comment: I have defined the driver as private in the base class, but I have a driver return method and it is the first thing I call in the test class. I'll try declaring it as public.